# how to use wait for condition in RIDE python robot frame work

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Cxd.jpg)Can someone help how to use wait for condition in RIDE Robot Framework PYTHON?

I get this error everytime, but it stops at this point. I want it to proceed to next command.

---

```
Country Code Creation 2                                                          | FAIL |

Element '//*[@id="mainBody"]/div[7]/p' not visible after 3 seconds.
```

---

> Project1.TestSuite1
>   | FAIL | 2 critical tests, 1 passed, 1 failed 2 tests total, 1 passed,
>   1 failed

---

> Project1
>   | FAIL | 2 critical tests, 1 passed, 1 failed 2 tests total, 1 passed,
>   1 failed

Comment: [Wait Until Keywords Succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still "Keyword 'Enter Numeric Digits for Country Code' failed after retrying for 1 second. The last error was: No keyword with name 'Enter Numeric Digits for Country Code' found." 

Case Which im trying is  ::: on negative case submit[button] i get this, to Enter Numberic that time its not proceeding to next command it stops in the same screen. my requirement is i need to close it after that. [Actually im expecting success with wait until elemenis visible but i get to enter Numeric, Im struck here its either not closing or identifying this Enter tag.]

Comment: You appear to be using it correctly. It's telling you it's not visible. If you were using it incorrectly it would throw a different error.

Comment: but :( y it stops at this point, I am new to this tool.. is there a way where i 
"Wait Unitl Element is visible" - Element '//*[@id="mainBody"]/div[7]/p' not visible after 3 seconds. " it logged failure but it is not going to my next command. I just want to close after this comes.

Comment: When you use "wait for condition" you're stating "I expect this condition to be true. If it's not true, fail the test", which is exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Can you update your question with the Robot script examples you've tried and their respective results. At present we're guessing to what happens and how you coded it.

Comment: Input Text    id=COUNTRY_CODE    qqq
    Sleep    2s
    Input Text    id=COUNTRY_NAME    CountryNew
    Sleep    2s
    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="createCountryWizard"]/div/ul/li[4]/a
    SeleniumLibrary.Wait Until Element Is Visible    //*[@id="mainBody"]/div[7]/p    timeout=3s 
    Close Browser


------ I'm using this. I may be wrong please help to correct. Attached Image in question

Comment: I have used wait until element is visible - Actually in this case element is not visible so it does not go to next command. I want to use some command which search the element is visible if not fail in logger and proceed to next command which is Close. Please help.

Comment: I used TearDown to close the window. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Run Keyword And Continue On Failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure) keyword should help you

For your case, it will be

```
Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Click Element    //*[@id="mainBody"]/div[7]/p    3s
```